# Weak convergence of probability measures.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** *Let $E$ be a metric space. Let $\{\mathbb{P}_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ a probability measure sequence. If $\{\mathbb{P}_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ weakly converges to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ in $(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$, then $$\limsup_n \mathbb{P}_n(A)\le \mathbb{P}(A),$$ where $A\in\mathcal{B}(E)$ is a closed set*.

**Proof.** Let $\rho$ be a metric on $E$. Define $$f_A^{(\varepsilon)}(x):=\bigg(1-\frac{\rho(x,A)}{\varepsilon}\bigg)\vee 0\quad\forall\varepsilon >0$$ and $$A_\varepsilon:=\text{supp}f_A^{(\varepsilon)}=\{x\in E\;|\;f_A^{\varepsilon}(x)>0\}=\{x\in E\;|\;\rho(x,A)<\varepsilon\}.$$ Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}_n(A)=\int_E\mathbb{P}_n(dx)\chi_A(x)\le\int_E\mathbb{P}_n(dx)f_A^{(\varepsilon)}(x).$$ Then we have $$\limsup_n\mathbb{P}_n(A)\le\limsup_n\int_E\mathbb{P}_n(dx)f_A^{(\varepsilon)}(x)=\int_E\mathbb{P}(dx)f_A^{(\varepsilon)}(x)\le\mathbb{P}(A_\varepsilon)\xrightarrow[\varepsilon\downarrow0]{}\mathbb{P}(A).$$

**Question.**

> 1. Where did we use the fact that $A$ is a closed set? What if it isn't?
> 2. Why $\mathbb{P}(A_\varepsilon)\xrightarrow[\varepsilon\downarrow0]{}\mathbb{P}(A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\mathbb{P}_n=\delta_{1/n},$ note that $\mathbb{P}_n\to \delta_0$ weakly. Let $A=(0, \infty).$ It is clear that $\mathbb{P}_n(A)=1$ for all $n,$ and $\delta_0(A)=0.$ This shows that the conclusion is false if $A$ is not closed.

If you go through your proof, nothing stops you from defining $f^{\epsilon}_A.$ And $\chi_{A}\le f^{\epsilon}_A$ holds no matter what set $A$ you choose. But what property of $f^{\epsilon}_A$ is required to get $\limsup\int d\mathbb{P}_nf^{\epsilon}_A = \int d\mathbb{P}f^{\epsilon}_A$? Does that property hold if $A$ is open?

For your second question, note that $A\subseteq A_{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon.$ And, $A_{\epsilon_1}\subseteq A_{\epsilon_2}$ if $\epsilon_1\ge \epsilon_2.$ That is, $A_{\epsilon}$ decreases to $A.$ Now, you can use a version of MCT to obtain $\mathbb{P}(A_{\epsilon})\to \mathbb{P}(A).$ (And, in fact this also fails if $A$ is open.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand how to use the MCT

Comment: You can directly use the fact that if $A_n$ is a decreasing sequence of subsets such that $A=\cap_n A_n$, then $\mu(A_n)\to \mu(A).$ This is just the continuity property probability of $\mu.$

Comment: If you want to use $MCT,$ then observe that $f_n:=\chi_{A_n}$ is a decreasing sequence of functions that converges a.e. to $f=\chi_{A}.$ Now since $f_1$ is integrable, you can apply MCT to show that $\int f_n d\mu\to \int f d\mu.$